# C++ grid class (std::vector of cells) custom resizing function causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, resize, stdvector

I have a 2D grid class which is made up of cells, I must store the cells in a 1D `std::vector` (due to specification) that models the 2D grid.

I have written a `Grid::resize` function that resizes the grid to a new width and height but preserves the content of the grid within the kept region (all new cells are set to 
    `Cell::DEAD`).

I have written a resize function that when run causes a segmentation fault: 11, which I assume means the function is trying to access data outside the bounds of the vector but I am not sure where the error is.

Class

```
class Grid {
private:
    std::vector<Cell> grid_cells;
    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;
public:
    Grid(const unsigned int width, const unsigned int height);
}
```

Constructor code

```
Grid::Grid(const unsigned int width, const unsigned int height) {
    std::vector<Cell> cells(width*height);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<(width*height);i++){
        cells[i] = Cell::DEAD;
    }
    this->width = width;
    this->height = height;
    this->grid_cells = cells;
}
```

Resize function

```
void Grid::resize(const unsigned int new_width, const unsigned int new_height) {

    std::vector<Cell> new_cells(new_width*new_height);
    unsigned int x, y;

    for(x = 0; x < new_width; x++) {
        for(y = 0; y < new_height; y++) {

            if(x < this->width && y < this->height) {
                new_cells[get_index(x,y)] = this->grid_cells[get_index(x,y)];
            }
            else {
                new_cells[get_index(x,y)] = Cell::DEAD;
            }
        }
    }

    this->width = new_width;
    this->height = new_height;

    this->grid_cells = new_cells;
}
```

My code is being tested by running pre-made test suites on it, I believe the error comes from the body of the for loops because when I comment this out the test suite runs to the end but when its left it I get a segmentation fault and it stops running.

Edit:

`get_index` function for converting the 2D x,y coordinate to the 1D index:

```
const unsigned int Grid::get_index(const unsigned int x, const unsigned int y) const{
    return ((y * this->width) + x + 1);
}
```

Comment: What's `get_index`? If you can resize to a smaller width or height, then surely one of the indices will be out of bounds of the new vector.

Comment: coverts a 2D x,y coordinate into the 1D index of the vector

Comment: The question is why that (probably defective) function is not in question.

Comment: yes, sorry I have added it now

Comment: why it adds 1? Seems incorrect.

Comment: Ahh i believe the error may come from the fact it calculates index based on the current grids width, which wont work for the new_cells?

Comment: if (0,0) corresponds to index 1 then (m,n) does not correspond to `(m*width) + n + 1`, why not use 0-based indexing?

Comment: I updated it to remove the +1 and it runs fine now, thank you guys completely overlooked this function

Comment: Can't be correct, you should call new_cells.get_index(x, y) for new_cells.

Comment: So because the new_cells and current grid_cells could have different widths right?

Comment: Yes. Try calling `resize(1, 8)` on a 3x3 grid.

Comment: I ran the test suit which tests it against all possible resize's and it passed all tests, thanks guys!

Comment: Some reason you deleted your latest question today? I worked hard on that answer for you, and now it's just gone...

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Hi, yes sorry I originally deleted it because I realised I had stated the problem in the wrong way but I have restored it now in case someone else finds it useful. Thanks for answering the question

Comment: @Cesare Okay thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const unsigned int 
Grid::get_index(const unsigned int x, const unsigned int y) const{
    return ((y * this->width) + x + 1);
}
```

You are using the original grid width to compute the index in the new grid. They can be vastly different, so you will copy the wrong cell or access memory out of bound of `new_cells`

Furthermore, as it is, you always perform invalid memory accesses when trying to access the last cell with coordinate `(width-1, height-1)`, which is at `height*width - width + width -1 + 1 = height*width`. The last valid index for the vector is `height*width-1`

You could use a free function

```
unsigned int 
get_index(const unsigned int x, const unsigned int y, const unsigned int width) const{
    return (y * width) + x ;
}
```

and have

```
new_cells[get_index(x,y, new_width)] = this->grid_cells[get_index(x,y, this->width)]
```